# How to find who updated a non tracking field?

Tags: apex, history-tracking, field-history

As the title says my question is simple, I am looking for a way to find who updated a particular field for which history tracking is not enabled.

From the docs, it seems we can get this information if we have history tracking enabled, but in my case history tracking is not enabled and I need to know if there are any workarounds from experts here.

Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting one..@javanoob

Comment: @javanoob noway to do this yet

Comment: Stop and think about it, where are you going to grab these "snap-shots" from if they don't exist? If you didn't capture the information, it's lost. It's not as though you can run hard disk forensics on your database to recover the overwritten records; at least not unless you want to see if Salesforce can do it for you. $$$$$

Comment: @crmprogdev , I totally get it now. What should I do now? Close or Delete the post? Pls suggest.

Comment: @javanoob, is up to you. Who knows, someone else may have the same question at some point in time, see your question along with my comments, which will answer it for them. If you asked it, chances are someone else might. After all, you got 2 upvotes for having asked it.

Comment: Just curious, if you could, then why would there be a need to declare fields to be tracked?

Comment: @JeffO, Thanks for your comment. The reason I posted this question was because we had a situation in production and we wanted to know if there was any complex time consuming workaround to find who updated it.

Comment: Hi, with a combination of a formula field and a workflow we might be able to track it. We had a situation where we had to track 25fields in professional edition. So no coding allowed. Create a formula field say a boolean value(true/false) to capture whether the related field has been updated or not and a workflow on create&update + Boolean variable as true - we can then capture the lastmodifiedby as the person who made the change in that field. We can achieve the same in a trigger without a formula & workflow.